# Is there a way to add bearer token in the "urlpatterns" so that I can use the Rest API in a browser as well?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using the Rest Framework SimpleJWT for token authentication.

In postman I add the Bearer token in the Authorization tab and the API works fine.

When I try to use the API on a browser I do not have an option to pass the Bearer token. I am not sure how to pass the bearer token so the API works in the browser as well.

How can I pass the bearer token in headers.

Let me know if anymore info required, I am able to add all the code here.

Comment: path('/user/<str:token>', profile),

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add bearer token to url patterns. Url patterns are added just to match the urls.
The API won't work in the browser if you have implemented authentication.
You can test your APIs via postman (which you have already done) or implement these APIs in your frontend app.

Answer (score 0):

if you want test your API on browser there is an easy way for it You can use ModHeader extension that is available for Chrome and Firefox  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNamP.png)